# how to prevent ajax button to fire when filling table

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

How do I prevent the ajax event to get called on every row in the datatable I am filling. I only want the call to happen when I click the button.

This is using primefaces.

```
<p:column id="save">
                    <f:facet name="header">Spara</f:facet>
                    <!-- p:commandButton value="Visa lista" action="#{serviceScoreDB.saveScores(player, serviceHCP.myCurrentClub, 
                    serviceSerieType.mySerieType, aScore.playDate, aScore.totalScore, aScore.serieNo)}"  -->
                    <p:commandButton value="Visa lista">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{serviceScoreDB.saveScores(player, serviceHCP.myCurrentClub, 
                    serviceSerieType.mySerieType, aScore.playDate, aScore.totalScore, aScore.serieNo)}" />

                    </p:commandButton>      
                </p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

try put the following code in you commandButton component:

```
<p:commandButton value="Visa lista">
   <p:ajax event="click" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"  
      listener="#{serviceScoreDB.saveScores(player, serviceHCP.myCurrentClub, serviceSerieType.mySerieType, aScore.playDate, aScore.totalScore, aScore.serieNo)}" />
</p:commandButton>
```